# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [...\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\appname] is not valid

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, illegalargumentexception

I'm facing a problem. I wrote a dynamic web project which uses `jsp`. I added `tomcat server 8` to eclipse by adding server run time environment, then launched a project and eclipse threw me this error:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [C:\Users\Ajay Kulkarni-enEXL\Javaworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\bistip] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
```

How can I fix it? Struck here.
This might help:
This is WEB-INF:
[image: img]
This is META-INF:
[image: img1]

I'm trying to deploy `JunosDashboard`.

Comment: Using maven? or standard dynamic web project? Do a right click on the server and Clean the server, start the server again?

Comment: I'm using `standard dynamic web project`, will try all those, wait

Comment: I cleaned it, restarted sever, it didn't work

Comment: Go to this location - C:\Users\Ajay Kulkarni-enEXL\Javaworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\bistip and validate what is being deployed. If you have a doubt, post a screenshot of the folder structure as well please.

Comment: Check edited question

Comment: Directory structure? What is in the lib? WEB-INF? etc?

Comment: I've both `META-INF` and `WEB-INF` in that directory, will post another screen shot later

Comment: @aksappy: Please check re-edited question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89126/discussion-between-aksappy-and-ajay-kulkarni).

Comment: StackOverflow does not allow me to input more words. I have to put my solution here for those who have the same issue as me to refer to.  http://paste.openstack.org/show/798815/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add dependency for servlet

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your issue but i have the same issue i fixed it this way.